# Is there an easy way to clear a mercurial repository of artifacts?

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg

Sometimes I have to return to a really old branch when I depended on a ton of external libraries. Updating to the current branch removes the source files for those dependencies, but the artifacts are left there, as well as a few folders and such.

I would like to have a way to force a mercurial repo to be as if I had just cloned it from the remote (master) repository. I don't want to just nuke my repo and re-clone it, because that forces me to download hundreds of MB from the remote server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [purge extension](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/PurgeExtension), or if you are on an UNIX-like system: `hg st -nu0 | xargs -0 rm`.

Answer (score 4):

Why don't you clone not from remote server, but from your local repository? After that you could nuke your repo with old untracked files.

```
hg clone path_to_your_local_repo your_new_repo
```

After this you could map your new repo to your remote server in `hgrc` file